# Encountered an error in python with getpixel(). (getpixel() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am having some issues with PIL's getpixel() function I am giving it only two arguments but it is saying that I am putting 3? Here is my code:

```
 x = self.get_piece_center_position()[0] + search_array_x[check]
        y = self.get_piece_center_position()[1] + search_array_y[check]
        r, g, b = image.getpixel(x, y)
```

output: TypeError: Image.getpixel() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I also tried this:

```
x = self.get_piece_center_position()[0] + search_array_x[check]
        y = self.get_piece_center_position()[1] + search_array_y[check]
        r, g, b = image.getpixel((x, y))
```

output: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Thanks!

Comment: If I remember this question was asked earlier few hours ago and was closed.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish you would be correct, I just worded it poorly and did not understand it as much so I decided to try to get an answer with a clearer more in depth question!

Comment: you are only passing 1 argument to get_pixel (a tuple with x,y). just remove one set of parenthesis.  `r, g, b = image.getpixel(x, y)`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki not 100% sure what this means. but here's what the pil documentation says: 
Returns the pixel value at a given position.

Parameters
xy – The coordinate, given as (x, y). See Coordinate System.

Returns
The pixel value. If the image is a multi-layer image, this method returns a tuple.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki sorry I made an error in the post, it is edited now it was saying it without the tuple and with the tuple it produces a new error

Comment: Try `print(image.mode)`. It may be `RGBA`, in which case you'd need `r,g,b,a = image.getpixel((x,y))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that it was returning an RGBA value instead of an RGB value!

Here is my fix:

```py
r, g, b, a = image.getpixel((self.get_piece_center_position()[0] + search_array_x[check], self.get_piece_center_position()[1] + search_array_y[check]))
            if (self.check_piece_number((r, g, b)))
```